# Directly modify a specific item in a TKinter listbox?

Tags: listbox, python-2.7, tkinter

This is one of those just-making-sure-I-didn't-miss-anything posts.

I have a TKinter GUI in Python 2.7.3 that includes a listbox, and there are circumstances where I'd like to directly modify the text of a specific item at a known index.  I've scoured the documents and there's no `lb.itemset()` method or anything like it.  As best I can tell I have two options, either of which would work but just seem kind of klunky to me:

1. `lb.delete()` the old item and `lb.insert()` the new value for it at the same index (including a step to re-select the new value if the old deleted one happened to be selected).
2. Create a `listvariable` for the listbox, then use `get()` and `set()` on it -- with a pile of `replace`/`split`/`join` acrobatics in between to handle the differing string formats involved.

Is there some simpler, more direct way to do it that I'm missing?  Or have I turned up all the available options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming from silence that there's nothing I missed.  I went with option 2 -- the acrobatics weren't quite as complex as I'd thought.  I just created a behind-the-scenes list wrapped up in a class; every time I update the list, the class syncs up the content of the listbox by doing a `' '.join` on the list then setting the listbox's `listvariable` to the resulting string.